# Vim doesn't show a certain file with colors

Tags: vim, colors

Vim doesn't show a certain file with colors. However, renaming this file will avoid this problem. Besides, files of the same type don't have the same problem.

What can be a problem?

Comment: What are the names of the file? Specific informations would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post the file (better a minimal example file)?

Comment: Hi, hutchonoid's method is helpful! Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: If it works for you, accept the answer. Please try to stick to the SO-etiquette. And welcome to SO ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file extension is not recognized for syntax highlighting you can use `set syntax` command.

Here is an example to set the current window html syntax highlighting:

```
:set syntax=html
```

If you want to set the file extension to be recognized to a specific file extension I would follow the instructions here:

[vim: persistent :set syntax for a given filetype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666170/vim-persistent-set-syntax-for-a-given-filetype)

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked why a **certain file** doesn't use syntax coloring, here's the reason behind it:

**The swap file!**

You somehow changed the syntax value, which gets stored in the swap file. Renaming solves your problem, because Vim doesn't have the old swap file associated with it.
Yes, you fixed your problem by `:set syntax=foo`. But if you encounter problems, which only apply to a **specific file**, then it's rooted always in the swap file! There are tons of problems like this, which can be solved by deleting the swap file and therefore restoring the default expected behaviour.

The variable for the swap directory can be set like this:
`:set dir=~/vimfiles/swap` (my swap)

Defaults from Vims help (`:h dir`):

```
for MS-DOS and Win32: ".,c:\tmp,c:\temp"  
for Unix: ".,~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp")
```