# Vim syntax highlighting disabled on certain files

Tags: vim

I have syntax highlighting enabled within my .vimrc file.  Most files load with syntax highlighting working from start.  Other files (with same extensions) will open without syntax highlighting on.  I then set `:syntax on` and it works, but i have to do it every time i open that particular file.  I've searched for answers but nothing has worked for me.

Frustrated.  Ideas?

Comment: What file type(s) doesn't it work for?

Comment: You may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666170/vim-persistent-set-syntax-for-a-given-filetype

Comment: This is a rails project and the files are .rb .   Some .rb files work others don't.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://superuser.com/questions/178412/how-do-i-enable-syntax-highlighting-for-bash-aliases-in-vim

Comment: This is for a different problem.  My syntax highlight works on many files and doesn't on others.  All files are the same extension and type.